# Python there are 8 numbers add up till less than certain number

Tags: python-3.x

First of all, thank you so much for your time. Here is my question below:
There are random 8 numbers, a,b,c,d,e,f,g, and h.
I would like to randomly generate each number and keep adding the number till the sum of the numbers is equal to 100. Once the sum is larger than 100, I would like to change the equation. And the sum of all the numbers should be equal to 110 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h = 110).

For example,
a = b = 50, c=d=e=f=g=h=2
the sum of the numbers is equal to 100 (in this case a+b = 100)

`result = tan(a) + tan(b) + sin(c)+sin(d)+sin(e)+sin(f)+sin(g)+sin(h)`

Example 2
let's say a = b = c = d =25, e=f=g=h=2.5
the sum of the numbers is equal to 100 (in this case a+b+c+d = 100)
`result = tan(a)+tan(b)+tan(c)+tan(d)+sin(e)+sin(f)+sin(g)+sin(h)`

Hope this makes sense. I am just not sure how to code using pyhton. Little help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.